# language grammar problem for allocate memory in our project

Tags: c++, memory, grammar, new-operator

I find a 'new' code in our project, like:

```
class A
{
public:
A(int x);
};

void func()
{

  A* pA = nullptr; 
  new (pA) A(123);  // what is this line meaning?

}
```

the 'new' function just like

```
void* operation new(int size);
```

I know this line is allocate some memory for 'pA', but why grammar like that? Thanks!:)

Comment: it looks like a *placement new*, but it is weird that `nullptr` is specified as where to initialize the object.

Comment: *I know this line is allocate some memory for 'pA'*. Nop. That line means undefined behaviour.

Comment: *"what is this line meaning?"* that means the person that wrote that line of code knows just enough about placement-new to be dangerous.

Comment: See here for how __Placement new__ should be used (search for "Placement new") - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: Thanks  @RichardCritten this is i want to know! Thanks!:)

Comment: @MikeCAT this is just a pseudo-code from my memory, actually, I just see this code 1 times.....